# RegEx to allow hyphens (maximum 3) in a string but do not count it in length

Tags: java, regex

My requirement is to limit the length of the input string to 11 which can be alphanumeric with hyphens. The maximum allowable hyphens are 3 and hyphens shouldn’t be considered in length. Another requirement is to not allow more than 5 continuous repetitive digits.

My Regex is `^(?!.*([0-9])\\1{5})(?=.*([-]){0,3})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$`

Comment: Does the input need to be 11 characters (other than hyphen) exactly or is there a minimum?

Comment: *Still, the hyphen is not allowed in the input string* - so what are the requirements? Can there be hyphens or not?

Comment: @JvdV, Input needs to be 11 characters exactly. There is no minimum.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Hyphen has to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way is:

```
^(?!.*?(\d)\1{5})(?=(?:[a-z0-9]-?){11}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+){0,3}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITW09L/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.*?(\d)\1{5})` - Negative lookahead to assert input has no digit that is repeated 6 times;
- `(?=(?:[a-z0-9]-?){11}$)` - Positive lookahead to assert input has 11 alphanumeric characters (with optional hyphens);
- `[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+){0,3}` - 1+ Alnum chars followed by a non-capture group (0-3 times) to allow for hyphens;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Note that it would not allow for hyphens to be at either: start, end or consecutive. Further note that I used the case-insensitive flag.

Comment: Hi @JvdV,
Thanks for the clear explanation. I am trying to implement the same logic in the oracle database script like `IF(REGEXP_LIKE(<myInput>,'(?=(?:[0-9]-?){11}$)') AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(<myInput>,'([0-9])(\1){5}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(<myInput>,'^[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+){0,3}$'))` THEN ....
Do u see any issue here? Only the second Regular Expression(More than 5 continuous repetitive digits) is working properly. It is not taking input with hyphens.